# Leaks in SDL2 when printing pixels

Tags: c, multithreading, memory-leaks, sdl, sdl-2

I'm developing an application using SDL2, and I'm facing some leaks which seems related to the `SDL_RenderDrawPoint` function.

My code where the leaks happens looks like this

```
void        set_img_pixel(t_img *img, int x, int y, t_color color)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < img->res.width && y >= 0 && y < img->res.height)
    {
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&img->mutex);
        SDL_SetRenderTarget(img->renderer, img->img);
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(img->renderer, color.r * 255, color.g * 255,
            color.b * 255, 255);
        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(img->renderer, x, y);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&img->mutex);
        pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    }
}
```

When I try to comment out `SDL_SetRenderTarget` and `SDL_RenderDrawPoint`, I have no leaks.
I have one leak on each thread of my app, and the leaks appears only when the thread(s) have finished their work, which means when they have finished rendering and they call `pthread_exit(NULL)`.

Here is the function which calls my `set_img_pixel`

```
static int      render_scene_p2(t_env *env)
{
    int             x;
    int             y;
    unsigned int    current_pixel_cpy;

    ft_lock_mult_thread(env);
    current_pixel_cpy = env->processed_pixels;
    env->processed_pixels++;
    ft_unlock_mult_thread(env);
    if (current_pixel_cpy >= (unsigned int)(env->scene->camera->res.height *
        env->scene->camera->res.width))
    {
        env->finish = 0;
        return (0);
    }
    y = current_pixel_cpy / env->scene->camera->res.width;
    x = current_pixel_cpy % env->scene->camera->res.width;
    set_img_pixel(&env->bg_img, x, y, get_pixel_color(env, x, y));
    return (1);
}

void            *render_scene(void *arg)
{
    t_env *env;

    env = (t_env *)arg;
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_DEFERRED, NULL);
    while (1)
    {   
        if (render_scene_p2(env) == 0)
            break ;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: How do you know there is a leak? What valgrind have to say? What are you doing with threads? SDL rendering API is not multithreadable, even with mutexes.

Comment: I'm using Xcode `leaks` program, as Valgrind shows me an error when I try to start it. My threads are rendering using pthread mutexes, that's why I don't understand when you say "SDL rendering API is not multithreadable", because it's working, and just leaking.

Comment: https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryRender "This API is not designed to be used from multiple threads", with link to bugtracker that explains why. In some cases in may work (depending on OS and rendering backend), but in others it explodes. I don't think there is a point in fixing something that shouldn't work.